# What transformation can I apply to a random vector to make its cumulative sum strictly negative (or positive)?

Tags: distributions, data-transformation, cumulative-distribution-function, splines

$X$ is a random vector of real numbers.

What is a good $f(X)$ such that $Y = f(X)$ satisfies $\displaystyle\sum_{i <k} Y_i < 0$ for all values of $Y$, where $Y$ has $k$ elements indexed with $i$?  $Y$ has the same dimension as $X$.

IOW:  the cumulative sum is negative.

Also: Y can be negative. I realize that one could trivially do this just by squaring $X$

For context:  I'm trying to make a spline regression have a strictly negative first derivative.

Edit 1: specify that I'm really just after a cumulative sum

Edit 2: you could trivially do this by squaring or exponentiating X. I want Y defined on the reals.

Comment: Re "CDF is negative:" impossible, because every value of a CDF is a probability.  Please explain what you intend to mean.

Comment: I may be speaking loosely. I need the cumulative sum to be negative. If you divide any distribution by it's sum then it's all the same, no?

Comment: @whuber edited.

Comment: I can't make any sense of this, especially once I reach the statement "do this just by squaring $X$."  Because that produces *non* negative values, there's no way a cumulative sum of the squares could ever be negative.  It's essential that you pose the actual question you have, rather than trying to present some abstract formulation.  "Strictly negative first derivative" sounds like you are trying to perform some kind of [monotone regression.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=monoton*+regression+spline).

Comment: @whuber forgive me for omitted the obvious, but if you multiply a square by a negative number, I think you might get a negative number

Comment: I am basically looking for a transformation for coefficients for a linear spline basis regression . I was going to fit using a nonlinear optimizer, or maybe mcmc. I'll read up on the basis functions that monotone splines use

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is ever interested, I found an answer:

To take a random vector $X$ and transform it to a vector $Y$ with support on the whole real line but with a cumulative sum that is strictly positive (or negative if you multiply by -1), do the following:

1. Convert it to strictly positive.  Exponentiate, or something.
2. Take its lag, prepending a zero, denote it $X_{lag}$
3. Subtract: $Y = X-X_{lag}$

```
b = np.exp(np.random.normal(size = 100))
blag = np.concatenate([[0] ,b[:-1]])
(np.cumsum(b-blag)>=0).all()
```

Pretty simple in retrospect.  But then, it's always simple in retrospect :)